# onto but not one-to-one on set of Natural Numbers

Tags: functions

Let $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, ...\}$.
Is there a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ which is an onto function but not one-to-one function?

I have tried it but could not find any such function.

Comment: Please, don't write "one-to-one" as "1-2-1". To answer your question, try $f(x)=x-1,f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes many, for example $$f(2n) = f(2n+1) = n$$

Comment: how is this a function please?

Answer (score 3):

Just do a left-shift
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } n = 0\\
n-1 & \text{ if } n > 0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just take $f$ defined by $f(0) = 0$, and $f(n+1) = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another assignment:
$$n \mapsto \left\lfloor \frac n5\right\rfloor$$
For each number $n$ is returns the fifth part of $n$ truncated to the nearest lower integer, so it is:
$0$ for $n=0\dots 4$,
$1$ for $n=5\dots 9$,
$2$ for $n=10\dots 14$,
$3$ for $n=15\dots 19$,
and so on.